# Nodejs api structure on calling sql helpers inside another helper all called by a controller

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm studying to create a simple API with mysql. I've understood and implemented the simple structure in which the app call the router, that call the controller, that call the service. But now i'm developing a multiple tag service module and I've realized that I need to call the same sql queries services declared in it. I show you the code for a better understanding:

tag_service.js:

```
const mysql = require("../../config/database");

module.exports = {
  insertTags: async (data, callBack) => {
    const connection = await mysql.connection();
    let results = '';
    const tagsArray = data.tags.map(tag => [data.id_manager,data.cod_table,data.id_record,tag])
    try {
      //console.log("at insertCallout...");
      await connection.query("START TRANSACTION");
      results = await connection.query(
        `INSERT INTO s_com_tags (id_manager,cod_table,id_record,tag) 
        VALUES (?,?,?)`, 
        [tagsArray]
      );      
      await connection.query("COMMIT");   
    } catch (err) {
      await connection.query("ROLLBACK");
      //console.log('ROLLBACK at insertCallout', err);
      throw err;
    } finally {
      await connection.release();
      return callBack(null, results);
    }
  },
  deleteTags: async (data, callBack) => {
    //console.log(data);
    let results = '';
    const connection = await mysql.connection();
    try {
      //console.log("at deleteCallouts...");
      await connection.query("START TRANSACTION");
      results = await connection.query(
        `DELETE FROM s_com_tags 
         WHERE cod_table = ? AND id_record = ? AND tag IN (?)`,
        [data.code_table, data.id_record,data.tags]
      );
      //console.log(res);
      await connection.query("COMMIT");   
    } catch (err) {
      await connection.query("ROLLBACK");
      //console.log('ROLLBACK at deleteCallouts', err);
      throw err;
    } finally {
      await connection.release();
      return callBack(null, Callouts);
    }
  },
};
```

controller's structure that will use the service:

```
module.exports = {
    updateLabDesc: async (req, res, next) => {
      try {    
        const body = req.body;
        if(!body.internal_code){
            updateLabDesc(body.manager, async (err, results) => {
            if (err) { 
              return next(createError.InternalServerError())
            }           
          });
        }
        updateTags(body, async (err, results) => {
          if (err) { 
            return next(createError.InternalServerError())
          }        
          return res.json({
            success: (results ? 1 : 0 ),
            message: (results || 0) + " LabDesc inserted successfully"
          });          
        });
      } catch (error) {
        next(error)
      } 
    },
  };
```

But the update is something like

```
updateTag function => {
try {    
  const current_tags = await getTags(req.body);
  let newTags = [];
  let oldTags = [];
  req.body.tags.forEach(tag => {
    if(!current_tags.includes(tag))
      newTags.push(tag)
  });
  await insertTags(newTags);
  current_tags.tags.forEach(tag => {
    if(!req.body.tags.includes(tag))
      oldTags.push(tag)
  });
  await deleteTags(oldTags);
} catch (error) {
  next(error)
} 
},
```

Basically, the tag_service has insertTags and deleteTags but I need the updateTags to call these functions as well. The final controller will call insertTags, deleteTags and updateTags. How can I structure these calls?
It is a controller that could call 2 helpers (insertTag and deleteTags) and another helper (updateTags) that call these 2 helpers. Any ideas?

Comment: What's missing from this question: **A** - The exact versions of the libraries you use. You seem to be using mysql, but the [standard variant of that library](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) does not support async/await, so you must be using something else. **B** The full description of *a single* error or issue you are running into, including sample input, desired results, actual results, and any errors you get. This question seems to revolve around more than one issue, and none of them is spelled out. Reduce the code to an [mcve] about *one* of them.

Comment: One of the issues you have seems to be *"How can I use the `IN` operator to select/update/delete more than one row?"* and this has been answered. Have a look around, there will be more than one example that explains how to do this.